# Remove acsii issue in a column

Tags: r, regex

In a column like this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("keep<U+0E1E>it"))
```

is there any way to use a gsub in column text to remove character which are inside this <> and remove also this <>

Expected output `data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("keep it"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using stringr package:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("keep<U+0E1E>it"))
df
  id           text
1  1 keep<U+0E1E>it
df %>% mutate(text = str_remove(text, '<.*>'))
  id   text
1  1 keepit
```

Using gsub:

```
gsub('<.*>','',df$text)
[1] "keepit"
```